# How to change status bar font color in ionic 4 app

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have been trying to change the font's color of `status bar in android app`. Build with `ionic 4`.

I changed the **background color** with some options in **config.xml**. And works.

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#2873ed" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

But, how can I change the font color?

Answer (score 0):

**page.ts**

```
    ionViewWillEnter() {

    this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
    this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#5d5e5e');
  }
```

safe side install , its already installed but many times give **error** so,

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install @ionic-native/status-bar --save
```